# Twig – time ago format

Tags: php, twig

I'm new to Twig and I'm looking to turn a `datetime` format into a *time ago* like **2 hours ago** or **3 days ago**. There is a jquery plugin (jquery-timeago) that I've been using on the client side but it would be great if I can do this with twig. If twig doesn't come with this filter format are there extensions that I can use?

Answer (score 22):

Twig's date extension does exactly what you ask:

```
{{ post.published_at|time_diff }}
```

> The example above will output a string like **4 seconds ago** or in **1 month**, depending on the filtered date.

See http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/date.html (no longer works) Working link http://twig-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/date.html

To make this work, follow these steps:

```
composer require twig/extensions
```

When working with symfony add this to your services.yml

```
services:
  twig.extension.date:
    class: Twig_Extensions_Extension_Date
    tags:
    - { name: twig.extension }
```

Comment: Unfortunately that filter gives undefined (or null?) if the difference is 0 seconds. So, you have to use `{{ post.published_at|time_diff ? : 'just now' }}`. I recommend writing a custom filter as suggested above.

Comment: That link does not work. Has this feature been removed from twig?  Is there a way to do it now?

Comment: in twig/extensions github page it says "This repository is abandoned in favor of Twig Core Extra extensions.". Anyways I tried to install and run time_diff filter. But it returned diff.xxx.xxx string, I could not solve, and then tried  KnpTimeBundle.  KnpTimeBundle worked fine.

Answer (score 15):

I found out I can create a custom filter with twig [`Twig_SimpleFilter`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#filters).

```
$filter = new Twig_SimpleFilter('timeago', function ($datetime) {

  $time = time() - strtotime($datetime); 

  $units = array (
    31536000 => 'year',
    2592000 => 'month',
    604800 => 'week',
    86400 => 'day',
    3600 => 'hour',
    60 => 'minute',
    1 => 'second'
  );

  foreach ($units as $unit => $val) {
    if ($time < $unit) continue;
    $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);
    return ($val == 'second')? 'a few seconds ago' : 
           (($numberOfUnits>1) ? $numberOfUnits : 'a')
           .' '.$val.(($numberOfUnits>1) ? 's' : '').' ago';
  }

});
```

Then I add it to my Twig environment:

```
$twig = $app->view()->getEnvironment();//because I'm using Twig in Slim framework
$twig->addFilter($filter);
```

Use it my template like this:

```
{{2014-10-11 12:54:37|timeago}}
```

Comment: I know it's a while since you posted it, but is there a way to add translations to your solution? I was able to inject a Translator object in the service, but Symfony doesn't recognize the "translation-ids".

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Twig inside of Symfony, check out [KnpTimeBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpTimeBundle).  Includes "ago" support in multiple languages.